# ReactJs is not reading map function inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I want to fetch 3 different things from firestore, hence have applied 3 useEffect in my code, out of which my react is not reading the map function inside 3rd useEffect. Here this map function in 3rd useEffect is not working

Code:
1st useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        var applications = [];
        const hospitals = [];
        const studentId = [];
        const details = [];
        firebaseConfig
            .firestore()
            .collection("counselor")
            .doc(currentUser.uid)
            .collection("studentDetails")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach((detail) => {
                    let currentID = detail.id;
                    let appObj = { ...detail.data(), ["id"]: currentID };
                    details.push(appObj);

                    details.push(detail.data());
                });
                setDetails(details);
                
            });
}, []);
```

2nd useffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const item = [];

        details.map((detail) => {
            console.log(detail.id);
            firebaseConfig
                .firestore()
                .collection("counselor")
                .doc(currentUser.uid)
                .collection("studentDetails")
                .doc(detail.id)
                .collection("studentApplications")
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    snapshot.docs.forEach((detail) => {
                        let currentID = detail.id;
                        let appObj = { ...detail.data(), ["id"]: currentID };
                    

                        item.push(detail.data().applicationStatus);
                    
                        setStudentId(item);
                    });

                
                });

        });

        setDemo(item);
    
    }, [details]);
```

3rd useeffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        demo.map((hii) => {
            
            if (hii === "PaymentFormFilled") {
                complete = complete + 1;
                setCom(complete);
            }
        });
    }, [demo]);
```

Comment: What is initial of `demo`?

Comment: initial of demo is an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not clear: "react is not reading the map function...".

There could be several issues:

- Is setDemo assigning a value to a state variable called *demo*? If not, your 3rd useEffect won't be triggered
- What is the value assigned to *demo*? You might not run .map on it

Comment: 1. yes setDemo is assigning value to demo

Comment: 2. its an array

Answer (score 0):

Because `setCom` is async. state `complete` only update value when component re-render. Please move `setCom` to the outside loop. And using `forEach` instead `map` in this case.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let newCount = complete;
  demo.forEach((hii) => {
    if (hii === "PaymentFormFilled") {
      newCount += 1;
    }
  });

  setCom(newCount);
}, [demo]);
```

Comment: the forEach function is not running, the console.log that i did, react is not reading that too, please let me know what shall i do for this.                                                                                                                            
  useEffect(() => {
  let newCount = complete;
  demo.forEach((hii) => {    console.log('inside forEach')
    if (hii === "PaymentFormFilled") {
      newCount += 1;
    }
  });

  setCom(newCount);
}, [demo]);